# rock combo -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

> The background-attachment property is little used, but very effective. On the web site for top **rock combo** Dirty Pretty Things (www.dirtyprettythingsband.com), a fixed background image was declared in the body selector, ensuring the background image stayed stationary while the main container and everything inside it scrolled as would be expected (see Figure 5-19).

I suppose the word *top* in that phrase means something like *the best* but what exactly does **rock combo** mean?

Comment: See [combo](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/combo) and substitute rock music for jazz. As in the url, it is a band.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colloquial term for a rock band/group, I would imagine.

Comment: Yes: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/combo